# Easy way to prevent add object with the same value to array

Tags: javascript

Like in title easy way to prevent add object with the same value to array

```
const array = [
  {
    name:'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark'
  }
]


array.push({name: 'John'}) //don't add

array.push({name: 'Kevin'}) //add

console.log(array)
```

Comment: please post here what you have tried so far

Comment: You could check if an item exist using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) `if(!array.some(item=>item.name===toAdd.name)) array.push(toAdd)`

Comment: Great thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prototype` constructor allows you to add new properties and methods to the `Array()` object.

So, you can create a method `addUser` and validate that the new user is unique:

```js
const array = [{name: 'John'},{name: 'Mark'}];

Array.prototype.addUser = function(user) {
  if (!this.some(u => u.name === user.name)) {
    this.push(user);
  }
  return this;
};

array.addUser({name: 'John'});  //don't add
array.addUser({name: 'Kevin'}); //add

console.log(array);
```